# Axiom of choice - Equivalence relation - Representatives

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $ X $ be a set and $ \sim $ an equivalence relation on $ X $.

In many proofs, a set of representatives of equivalence classes of $ X $ is used (e.g. coset or orbit representatives in groups, prime representatives in factorial rings, ...).

Do these proofs tacitly use the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need AC and sometimes not. For example, consider the equivalence relation on the reals such that $x \sim y$ if $x - y \in \mathbb{Z}$. The set of equivalence classes is denoted $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. I can choose a representative from each class by noting that each class has exactly one member in $[0,1)$. So I just choose that member as a representative, and $[0,1)$ is a complete set of representatives, one per class, and no Choice is needed.

On the other hand if we do the same thing with $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, as in the construction of the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set), we do need to apply AC because there's no way to specify a choice from each class.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose a representative without justification, you are using choice. However, for some situations, the hypothesis of the axiom of choice can be discharged if there is a better method of making the selection.

Comment: Only true if X is an infinite set, I think.

Comment: @TomCollinge No, that depends on $X$. If $X=\Bbb N$ or more generally if $X$ is well-ordered, then a choice function on its subsets is definable: simply choose the least element as representative.

Comment: The point is that unless you assume additional properties of the set, you only have access to choice. Finite sets, wellordered sets, countable sets, etc don't require full choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $Y$ be the set of equivalence classes of $X$ under $\sim$. Then $X=\bigcup Y$ and choosing a representative of each equivalence class is equivalent to defining a function $f:Y \to X$ such that $f(A)\in A$ for every $A\in Y$. By definition, such $f$ is a choice function of $Y$ whose existence is assured only if you assume the axiom of choice.

Of course, if $Y$ is finite, this requires the axiom of finite choice, which is deducible from $ZF$, so there's no real problem here. But as soon as $Y$ is infinite, you cannot guarantee, in general, the existence of such $f$ from $ZF$.

Comment: No that's not true, see my comment to the OP's question.

Comment: What is not true?

Comment: Nevermind, I had an error which I don't have time to fix right now. But it's not true that you always need Choice.

Comment: Yes, of course it's not true. But without AC, there is no way **in general** to find a choice function.

Comment: OP asked if all such proofs implicitly use Choice. The answer is no. OP did not explicitly say "all" but he said: "Do these proofs tacitly use the axiom of choice?" The meaning is clear to me. Are you interpreting the question as asking if SOME of the proofs require Choice?

Comment: First off, thank you all! But what if I use the power set $ 2^X $ of $ X $. As it contains any possible subset of $ X $, there must be at least on subset of $ X $ that contains one element of every equivalance class. Then I could say, Let R be such a subset? The power set should guarantee me the existence of such a set.