# Difficulty understanding Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The Axiom of Choice is defined by Mcdonald, A Course in Real Analysis as follows:

"Suppose that $C$ is a collection of non-empty sets. Then there exists a function $f: C \rightarrow \bigcup\limits_{A\in C}A$ such that $f(A)\in A$ for each $A \in C$."

I don't understand what it means for a function to exist between a collection and a union of sets in the collection. Also, how do we know that putting $A$ into the function returns an element of $A$?

Comment: $S=\cup_{A \in C}A$ is a set, isn’t it? So you can consider functions $C \rightarrow S$. For the second part of your question, the fact that we can choose $f$ as such (ie for all $A$, $f(A) \in A$) is exactly the axiom of choice.

Comment: It isn't "for some", but "for all".

Comment: @ Mindlack Yes, I understand a function is mapping between sets. I don't understand what it means in this case. For the second part, it seems arbitrary.

Comment: If you know what an equivalence relation on a given set $X$ is, maybe you can check out this: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1655923/axiom-of-choice-equivalence-relation-representatives). Because these kind of things you come a cross very often in all sorts of areas and very often you very much by definition need such a function to be able to pick a representative of any given equivalence class. Again, just if you are already familiar with this concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps an example will help.

Let $C = \{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\}\}$.

Notice that $\bigcup_{A \in C} A = \{1,2\} \cup \{2,3\} \cup \{3,4\} = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

The axiom of choice asserts, for this example, that

> *There exists* a function $f : C \to \bigcup_{A \in C} A$ such that $f(A) \in A$ for **each** $A \in C$.

And this statement is true, as you can easily verify on your own without even applying the axiom of choice, by simply choosing correct values of the function $f$, which I will leave it for you to fill in:
$$\begin{align*}
f(\{1,2\}) &= ? \quad\text{(choose some element of the set $\{1,2\}$)} \\
f(\{2,3\}) &= ? \quad\text{(choose some element of the set $\{2,3\}$)}\\
f(\{3,4\}) &= ? \quad\text{(choose some element of the set $\{3,4\}$)}
\end{align*}
$$

The hard part comes when the set $C$ is infinite. In this case, you cannot always write down the infinitely many choices to be made in order to specify the choice function $f$. The Axiom of Choice is nonetheless verifying that this function **exists**, despite our inability to write it down.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the mapping issue now for question 1. Regarding the second question: it seems very hand-wavy that we can obviate the selection issue by simply stating that "yes we can select something from a set". What am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything. Axioms are like that. Think about Euclid's axioms for points and lines in the plane, think about Euclid's parallel postulate: that's kind of hand-wavy too, especially if you remember that Euclid did not have Descartes' coordinate geometry at hand like we do.

Comment: Of course, we don't *want* to just make up axioms if we don't have to.  The whole idea behind axiomatic mathematics it to try to pin down the **rock bottom** set of axioms that are needed on which the proofs of mathematical theorems can be built.

Comment: Ah, so there is some element of "belief" then. At some point, we just have to believe a thing or it all falls apart?

Comment: You could take that point of view, although that's getting a bit too philosophical for me. Another point of view is that sometimes, if the axioms for a particular logical system are simple enough, then they can actually be *verified*. So, for example, the Axiom of Choice can be *verified* for a finite set $C$ by a simple induction argument (assuming that you accept Peano's Axioms for natural numbers and induction !!!!)

Comment: @senior_data_scientist To use a well-worn analogy, given infinitely many pairs of socks, the axiom of choice says there is a function maps each pair to a sock from that pair. To most people, it seems initially obvious such a function should exist, but we need an axiom to assert it since there's no "rule" we can write down to define the function since there is no obvious rule to distinguish the socks. Compare to the case of shoes where we just define the function maps each pair to the left shoe, so we don't need the axiom of choice in this case.

Comment: The axiomatic system ZF (Zermelo-Frankel) for Set Theory does not include AC (the Axiom of Choice). In the 1930's Kurt Godel proved that AC is consistent with ZF:  If $1=0$ is not a theorem of ZF then ZF cannot disprove AC. In the 1960's Paul Cohen invented Forcing and used it to prove that $\neg $AC is consistent  with ZF: If $1=0$ is not a theorem of ZF then ZF cannot prove AC.

Answer (score 0):

The axiom says that from a collection of sets, you can choose one element in every set, by means of function.

So the domain of the function is the collection, and the range is the set of elements contained in the members of the collection.