# How to formally define a bijection $f\colon (A/\sim)\to R$, where $R\subseteq A$ is a set of representatives?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Given a set $A$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $A$, how can I formally define a bijection $f\colon (A/\sim)\to R$, where $R\subseteq A$ is a set of representatives? Clearly, $[a]_\sim\mapsto a$ is not well-defined, because $a\ne b\in [a]_\sim\Longrightarrow [b]_\sim=[a]_\sim$, but $f([b]_\sim)=b\ne a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to define a bijection $g$ from $R$ to $A/{\sim}$ given by $g(a)=[a]_\sim$; then the bijection from $A/{\sim}$ to $R$ is simply $f=g^{-1}$.

If we want an explicit formula for $f$, perhaps $f([a])=[a]\cap R$ works.

Comment: Unless $A/\sim$ is made of singletons, $g$ doesn't seem to be injective, because $(b\ne a) \wedge (b\sim a)\Rightarrow g(a)=g(b)$, isn't it?

Comment: @user750041 a set of representatives doesn't contain $a\neq b$ with $a\sim b$

Comment: @MatthewTowers, you are right, so that's fine for $g$. The doubt I'm left with is about the explicit formula for $f$: I wish to build a "picking map" which chooses from every equivalence class *an* element of the class, *so as to to build up the set* $R$; but the the proposed formula *already uses* $R$, which is what bothers me. So maybe my real target is another question...

Comment: @user750041 that's the axiom of choice. More details here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1655923/axiom-of-choice-equivalence-relation-representatives in short, you're having problems making things explicit because being able to do so at all is an axiom in itself that doesn't follow from the rest of mathematics you know and use

Comment: @Bananach, as I'm not familiar with that, I'd appreciate a bit of formalization, in particular: does the axiom of choice imply (in this context) that there is a subset of $A$ which is equicardinal to $A/\sim$? If so, could you give a scketch of the proof, please? Or is this claim *precisely* the axiom of choice? Thanks. I'm just reading now your update, I'll go through it.